# Typescript - React 0.14 stateless functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

### Simple example:

```
import * as React from 'react'
declare function getFish(x: any): any;
declare var Tank: any;

var Aquarium = ({species}) => (
  <Tank>
      {getFish(species)}
  </Tank>
);
let x = <Aquarium species="rainbowfish"/>;
```

Result:

> (10,9): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Element' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.

Note the error is in regards to the **usage** of the Component (let x declaration). It seems as if maybe the definition file for React is not allowing this as a valid JSX? I am using the latest React 0.14 definition file from tsd, what am I doing wrong?

---

Say I have defined the following stateless functional component (React v0.14)

```
let GreeterComponent = (props: {name: string}){
    return <div>Hi {props.name}!</div> 
}
```

in a different component, I am using it like this:

```
class WrappingComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let names = ['tom', 'john', 'simon'];
        return (
           <div className="names">
               {names.map((name)=> <GreeterComponent name={name} />)}
           </div>
          );
    } 
}
```

I am getting this error from typescript compiler:

> error TS2605: JSX element type 'Element' is not a constructor function
>   for JSX elements. Property 'render' is missing in type 'Element'.

How can I fix it? What is the correct to work with stateless functional components in typescript? I am using the latest [react.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts) from tsd

Comment: could you please post a code example with this issue? And the error you are receiving. It will help us more easily find your problem.

Comment: Also, please read the how to ask a good question guide. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I am afk and posted from phone, will update my question shortly

Comment: @toskv - I edited my question with more info

Comment: Can you try adding type?

`let GreeterComponent: React.SFC `

Answer (score 0):

When you *define* a stateless component, it's a plain and simple function.

When you *instantiate* it (i.e. pass it to `React.createElement`), it gets wrapped with `React.StatelessComponent`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, I edited my question and added some more specific info, can you please take a look and perhaps help? Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

> error TS2605: JSX element type 'Element' is not a constructor function for JSX elements. Property 'render' is missing in type 'Element'.

That will work fine in TypeScript latest `npm install typescript@latest`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the typescript using **@next**:

### `npm install typescript@next --save-dev`

At the moment of this answer, the `@next` version is `1.9.0-dev.20160217`.

In the beginning I though the problem was with the `react.d.ts` or `react-dom.d.ts`... but it was not. The latest version of these are already installed here. But the real problem was I installed typescript version 1.7.5, the latest release.

**Some notes about this:** as per the blog post [Using typescript@next nightly package? Don’t rely on –save-dev to be up-to-date!](http://rostacik.net/2015/09/04/using-typescriptnext-nightly-package-dont-rely-on-save-dev-to-be-up-to-date/), you cannot rely on `npm` updating your dependency of `typescript` to a greater version number after installing with `@next` and `--save-dev`.

As they explain, `npm update` seems not to update from one beta version to the next:

e.g. The dependency string `"^1.6.0-dev.20150818"` (inside the `package.json`) will have the package updated to `1.6.0-dev.20150825`, but not to `1.7.0-dev.20150901` when running `npm update`

What they recommend is to change the dependency string that `npm --save-dev` saved inside your `package.json` to just `"next"` to be always with the latest of the latest version:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "typescript": "next",
    ...
  }
}
```

I personally didn't try it, because I like to have full control over the version I am using. I rarely run `npm update` anyway.